# Update Partial on Button Click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to update a partial on a button click. 
The partial already exists in the view.

```
<div id="partial_to_update">
  <%= render partial: "accounts/all_accounts", :locals => { term: @term}  %>
</div>
```

On a click(lets say update partial link), I want to change the value of 'term' and re-render the same partial.

```
<%= link_to "Update Partial", update_accounts_path, :remote => true, id: "update-partial-link" %>
```

in routes, I added :

```
get '/update_accounts' => "accounts#update_accounts", as: :update_accounts
```

in accounts_controller :

```
 def update_accounts
  respond_to do |format|               
   format.js
  end        
 end
```

in views/accounts/update_accounts.js.erb:

```
$('#partial_to_update').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript( render partial: 'accounts/all_accounts', :locals => { term: 'new_term'} ) %>");
```

But, when I click on the "Update Partial", the partial just disappears. 
If I replaceWith("MY NAME"), it works.

Any help??

Comment: can you show how partial looks like in question?

Comment: i think you are not passing @new_term instance variable from your update_accounts action to update_accounts.js.erb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'update_accounts' action not passing instance variables to update_accounts.js.erb. What is 'new_term'?